# Ruby regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I understand how to check for a pattern in string with regexp in ruby. What I am confused about is how to save the pattern found in string as a separate string.

I thought I could say something like:

```
if string =~ /regexp/ 
  pattern = string.grep(/regexp/)
```

and then I could be on with my life. However, this isn't working as expected and is returning the entire original string. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`string.match()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000778) in ruby.

```
irb(main):003:0> a
=> "hi"
irb(main):004:0> a=~/(hi)/
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> a.match(/hi/)
=> #<MatchData:0x5b6e8>
irb(main):006:0> a.match(/hi/)[0]
=> "hi"
irb(main):007:0> a.match(/h(i)/)[1]
=> "i"
irb(main):008:0>
```

But also for working with what you just matched in the if condition you can use `$&` `$1`..`$9` and `$~` as such:

```
irb(main):009:0> if a =~ /h(i)/
irb(main):010:1> puts("%s %s %s %s"%[$&,$1,$~[0],$~[1]])
irb(main):011:1> end
hi i hi i
=> nil
irb(main):012:0>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the special variables $& and $1-$n, like so:

```
if "regex" =~ /reg(ex)/
  puts $&
  puts $1
end
```

Outputs:

```
regex
ex
```

$~ also contains the MatchData object. See also: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer some shortcuts like:

```
email = "Khaled Al Habache <khellls@gmail.com>"
email[/<(.*?)>/, 1] # => "khellls@gmail.com"
```